# Reference parent window document

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to access the parent window document from a popup.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var summary = window.parent.document.getElementById('summary');
        var content = summary.innerHTML;
    });
</script>
```

Is it even possible? Is there a jQuery specific way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want `window.opener` not `window.parent` (that's for frames).

Answer (score 3):

You can use context to accessed it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var content = $("#summary",window.opener.document).html();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you opened the window with window.open(...), check out [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener)